# Magento Rest API Oauth URL getting 404 error

Tags: php, rest, magento

I have used Magento Rest API but getting 404 error. I have given below deatils

```
callbackUrl,
temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl,
adminAuthorizationUrl,
accessTokenRequestUrl,
apiUrl,
consumerKey,
consumerSecret
```

But when click on http/mydomain/api/rest then getting 404 error. Is there any option should enabled in admin ?

Comment: Can you show your full code?

Comment: My complete code to access the Magento cart application using restful API by below url [link]http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-Overview[/link]